# What is the python way to iterate two list and compute by position?

Tags: python

What is the Pythonic way to iterate two list and compute?

```
a, b=[1,2,3], [4,5,6]
c=[]
for i in range(3):
    c.append(a[i]+b[i])
print(c)
[5,7,9]
```

Is there a one-liner for `c` without a for loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `zip` and list comprehension:

```
[x+y for (x, y) in zip(a, b)]
```

Comment: Note that this is still a `for` loop.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 just like everything in programming?

Answer (score 8):

One possibility:

```
a, b = [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]
c = list(map(sum, zip(a,b)))
```

Another option (if it's always just two lists):

```
c = [x + y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

Or probably my favorite, which is equivalent to my first example but uses list comprehension instead of `map`:

```
c = [sum(numbers) for numbers in zip(a, b)]
```

To generalize to a list of lists (rather than a fixed number of lists in different variables):

```
lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
c = [sum(numbers) for numbers in zip(*lists)]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing this sort of thing often, you should be using `numpy`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a, b=[1,2,3], [4,5,6]
>>> c = np.array(a) + b
>>> c
array([5, 7, 9])
```

Answer (score 3):

`zip` is the way to go, but the actual title of your question suggests `enumerate`:

```
[x+b[i] for i, x in enumerate(a)]
```

This sort of thing is helpful if you need the actual *position* (index) in the computation.

Comment: you might need to swap a and i? so it should be [a+b[i] for i, a in enumerate(a)]

Comment: @milesma Good catch. I had `zip` on my mind when I wrote that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `izip` is a better choice, it will not generate a list of tuples.

```
from itertools import izip

c = [x + y for x, y in izip(a, b)]
```